# Why is a javascript function (mapped to button) not fully executing on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, iphone, reactjs, function, mobile

**Edit, i figured it out, and by i figured it out, I mean that I have no clue how the problem fixed itself because this exact code is still being run but it just started to work on my phone now. probably a device specific issue or something.**

I have tested this `handleSubmit()` function on desktop with all sorts of ChromeDev screen sizes, so that's not the issue.

I have debugged my code with alert statements (I know) and tracked the break point (in mobile) up to my `showPosition()` function. It never evaluates, even though it needs to, on mobile, but everything evaluates perfectly fine on desktop.

If you kind of take a trek through my nest of functions, here is expected behavior:

1. alert(if eval)
2. alert(started showposition)
3. alert(state set)
4. alert(past getLocation) **rerun of this.handlesubmit**
5. alert(past getLocation) **rerun of this.handlesubmit**
6. alert(past indexdata)
7. alert(past loop)
8. redirect: details page

observed behavior on iOS chrome & safari:

1. alert(if eval)

**TLDR:**

**Works perfectly, all browsers: Windows 10**

**button doesnt work, all browsers: iOS 12 with Javascript `ON` and Safari Location Services `While using the app`**

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';
import LocationIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocationSearchingOutlined';
import searchClient from '../components/SearchClient';

const index = searchClient.initIndex("Parks");

class ButtonComponent extends React.Component{
    state = {
        loading: false,
        userlat: null,
        userlong: null,
        parkData: null,
    };
    render(){
        const loading = this.state.loading;
        return(
            <div>
                <Button color="secondary" variant="contained" size="large" onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()} style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: "#FFFFFF"
                }}>
                    Find the nearest point of interest
                    <LocationIcon style={{
                        paddingLeft: '10px',
                    }} />
                </Button>
                <Fade in={loading}>
                    <LinearProgress/>
                </Fade>
            </div>
        )
    }

    showPosition = (position) => {
        alert('started showPosition');
        this.setState(state => ({
            userlat: position.coords.latitude,
            userlong: position.coords.longitude,
        }));
        alert('state set');
        this.handleSubmit();
    };

    getLocation = () => {
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
            alert('if eval');
        }
        else {
            alert("Geolocation isn't supported by device hardware.");
            this.state.loading = false;
        }
    };

    indexData = () => {
        const browser = index.browseAll("", {
            attributesToRetrieve:[
                'latLong',
                'parkCode',
            ]
        });
        let hits = [];

        browser.on('result', content => {
            hits = hits.concat(content.hits);
            this.state.parkData = hits;
            this.handleSubmit();
        });

        browser.on('end', () => {
            console.log(`${hits.length} total responses.`);
        });

        browser.on('error', err => {
            throw err;
        });
    };

    calculateDistance = (coords) => {
        if (coords.length < 2){
            return 360;
        }
        else{
            return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(coords[1] - this.state.userlong, 2) + Math.pow(coords[0] - this.state.userlat, 2));
        }
    };

    handleSubmit = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            loading: true
        }));
        if(this.state.userlat == null || this.state.userlong == null){
            this.getLocation();
            return false;
        }
        alert('past getlocation');
        if(this.state.parkData == null){
            this.indexData();
            return false;
        }
        alert('past indexdata');
        var nearestPOI = {
            parkCode: null,
            lat: 180.0,
            long: 360.0,
            distance: 360.0
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.parkData.length; i++){
            const parkCoords = this.state.parkData[i].latLong.replace(/[^\d.,-]/g, '').split(",").map(Number);
            const parkDistance = this.calculateDistance(parkCoords);
            if (parkDistance < nearestPOI.distance){
                nearestPOI.parkCode = this.state.parkData[i].parkCode;
                nearestPOI.lat = parkCoords[0];
                nearestPOI.long = parkCoords[1];
                nearestPOI.distance = parkDistance;
            }
        }
        alert('past loop');
        console.log(nearestPOI.parkCode);
        window.location.href = "/details?objectId=" + nearestPOI.parkCode;
    }
}

export default ButtonComponent;
```

I have tried changing the following line

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
```

to

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(() => this.showPosition());
```

without success.

Comment: Does it work on Safari for desktop? Mac? Android? ...by isolating the problem you'll have a better chance of knowing if it's a browser related issue or, for example, something related with permissions on IOS, or whatever.

Comment: windows safari is outdated and there are too many random variables to account for if my app didn't work on it, as its no longer officially supported or available for download, i dont have mac or android :/

Comment: ok, you are not developing on a Mac, on a windows 10 box instead, I presume. I'm going to take a closer look at your code. Looks like incompatibility problem, but at this stage I can't say.

Comment: @lusitanica the problem went away. I have no idea honestly what happened. I reverted my code back a few hours, restarted my computer, and then it started working on my phone. thanks for the help, this code should be fully functional